# Magento2.3: How to load custom JS in custom module?

Tags: module, magento2.3, javascript

I have created a custom module and now need to add custom js file into that module. I have read many post about this but not having a clear answer.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Magento 2 has unique functionality about uiComponents for rendering and js events using KO js..Please refer this - https://www.hexascholars.com/code-snippet/custom-uicomponent-creation-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2/

Comment: @Siva Have you resolved your query?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have to create a requirejs-config.js file in dir **Vendor/Module/view/frontend** to include your custom js file. I am taking an example of owlCaraulsel js.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery/owl.carousel.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now add your js file in dir of the module if its for frontend i.e.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/jquery/owl.carousel.min.js

Now you call this in you phtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','owlcarousel'], function(jQuery, owlcarousel) {
...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good and precise answer +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Add a custom JS component

To add a custom JS component (module), take the following steps:

1. Place the custom component source file in one of the following
   locations:

   - Your theme JS files: /web/js or
     /_/web/js. In this case the
     component is available in your theme and its child themes.
   - Your module view JS files: /view/frontend/web/js. In this
     case the component is available in all modules and themes (if your
     module is enabled).
2. Optionally, in the corresponding module or theme, create a
   requirejs-config.js configuration file, if it does not yet exist
   there and set path for your resource. The RequireJS configuration
   file can be placed in one of the following locations:

   - Your theme:
   - Module within your theme: /
   - Your module (depending on the needed area - base, frontend,
     adminhtml): /view/

> Replace a default JS component

To use a custom implementation of an existing Magento JS component: Place the custom component source file in one of the following locations:

- Your theme JS files: /web/js
- Your module view JS files: /view/frontend/web/js

Create a RequireJS configuration file requirejs-config.js, having specified the following:

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "<default_component>": "<custom_component>"
    }
  }
};
```

- `<default_component>:` the name of the default component you replace
- `<custom_component>:` the name of the custom component

For example, if you want to use custom navigation-menu.js script instead of the default menu widgets, your requirejs-config.js should contain the following:

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "menu": "js/navigation-menu",
      "mage/backend/menu": "js/navigation-menu"
    }
  }
};
```

Place your requirejs-config.js file in one of the following directories (according to the location of your custom script, see step 1 of this procedure):

- Your theme files:
- Your module view files: /view/frontend

This way your custom JS component is used instead of the Magento component in all entries all over the frontend area.

> Extend a default JS component

You can add a custom JS component/widget, which will extend a default Magento component/widget.

**Extend Magento widget:**

To extend a default Magento jQuery widget, create .js with the following contents:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui',
  'mage/<widget.name>' // usually widget can be found in /lib/web/mage dir
], function($){

  $.widget('<your_namespace>.<your_widget_name>', $.mage.<widget.name>, { ... });

  return $.<your_namespace>.<your_widget_name>;
});
```

Where the following notation is used:

- `<your_namespace>.<your_widget_name>` - the name of your custom widget. According to the jQuery widgets naming convention, must contain a namespace and name.
- `mage.<widget.name>` - the name of the Magento widget that you extend.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and let you know.